# Two same pages www.example.com and www.example.com/index.php

Tags: php, redirect, website, seo, www

Can someone help me how to fix this problem, seobility shows me that i have two same pages [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and [www.example.com/index.php](http://www.example.com/index.php)

Comment: This is normal and not a problem.

Comment: It all depends on your server setup, what you need to do. Without any details, this cannot be answered.